# Can't import pandas nor numpy, AttributeError: "module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'Generator'"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, error-handling, jupyter-notebook

I tried with updating everything (conda, ipython, numpy, pandas) but I always get an error AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'Generator' when trying to import numpy, pandas and sklearn.
I have no idea how to fix it,  did someone had a same problem in a last few days?

Comment: Have you restarted your kernel?  Assuming you are using iPython or Jupyter.

Comment: I did, it still does not work

Comment: What command line did you use to update your Numpy?  Seems like you deleted a file or directory or are using the wrong environment in which you installed.

Comment: I just downgraded it to numpy version 1.22.2 because it seems that there is a problem with version 1.22.3 and now it works.
But I used pip install numpy.

Comment: Then my suspicion is that you messed with the installed directory.  When you pip installed a version you were already on, it did nothing because you already had it.  Your downgrade forced the issue and fixed it.  I further suspect that if you upgraded again it should still work.  If I'm right, next time you can use a force flag on pip install to force the reinstallation of the current version.  Look that up to get exact command and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked again, when restarting the kernel. I´m using VSCode and notebook files.